# what is a fractional second?

Tags: date, time, double

I am trying to understand what a *fractional second* is.  I found a [fractional second,here](http://files.ettus.com/uhd_docs/doxygen/html/classuhd_1_1time__spec__t.html#a0cb21de29988aa22597d314951b8ee97):

```
double uhd::time_spec_t::get_frac_secs  (   void        )    const
     Get the fractional part of the time in seconds.

Returns:
     the fractional seconds
```

What exactly is a fractional second represented as a *double*?  Can someone give me an example value and how that translates in to seconds?

Comment: [The documentation](http://files.ettus.com/uhd_docs/doxygen/html/classuhd_1_1time__spec__t.html) has the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fractional second is the part of the time that is not an integer. So if you have a time like `12345678.9` the fractional second is `0.9`

Answer (score 5):

The example here may help you to understand what the fractional second is:

> ### TIMESTAMP{(fractional-seconds)}
>
> The optional parameter specifies the number of fractional seconds. If the parameter is not specified, the number of fractional seconds defaults to 6.
>
> The following example shows several timestamps, with different numbers of fractional seconds.

```
DCL-S TS0 TIMESTAMP(0);    // YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss
DCL-S TS1 TIMESTAMP(1);    // YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss.f
DCL-S TS6A TIMESTAMP;      // YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss.ffffff
DCL-S TS6B TIMESTAMP(6);   // YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss.ffffff
DCL-S TS12 TIMESTAMP(12);  // YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss.ffffffffffff
```

> via [IBM Knowledge Center - TIMESTAMP{(fractional-seconds)}](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/dkwtimestamp.htm)