# What exactly are fractional seconds returned by Python time.perf_counter()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timing

This is probably a dumb/obvious question, but just want to make sure my hunches are correct.

I'm doing some basic performance timing in a Python3 script using time.perf_counter() like so:

```
start = time.perf_counter()
# some time consuming operation here
end = time.perf_counter()
elapsed = end - start
```

And I'll get back values like 9.774 or 36.903 (to many more decimal places, of course). I'm assuming that larger numbers = more time elapsed, but what exactly do these numbers mean? E.g. is 1.23 fractional seconds just 1 second and .23 fractions of a second

Comment: When a number is returned, like 1.23 for example, is that 1 second and .23 fractions of a second?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I saw another post that had a weird answer, so I was confused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937708/what-is-a-fractional-second

Comment: Yeah I guess the term "fractional seconds" is a bit unusual, but they just mean seconds.

Comment: I agree that calling them "fractional seconds" is confusing. They are whole seconds, with fractions of a second resolution past the decimal point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, "fractional second" just means a second with a fractional part (as opposed to a strictly integer number of seconds). So 9.774 means 9 seconds plus 774/1000 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Additional info, for very small elapsed time it will return scientific notation like `3.6564000765793025e-05` then to format it to second and Milisecond/Microsecond

```
print(f'{elapsed:.3f} - Second & MiliSecond')
print(f'{elapsed:.6f} - Second & Microsecond')

# 0.000 - Second & MiliSecond
# 0.000037 - Second & Microsecond
```