# How to compute the return value of python's "time.process_time()" in milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time, performance-testing

I am using python 3.6.5 `time.process_time()` to compute some performance.

Here its description in its official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time):

> time.process_time() → float
>
> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process. It does not include time
>   elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by definition. The reference
>   point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference
>   between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

I used it in a similar way to this small example:

```
import time
x=0
start = time.process_time()
for x in range(100000):
    performance = time.process_time() - start

print("performance: ",performance)
```

Which gives me this output based on my machine (so I understand it can be different in another machine):

```
performance:  0.051401815000000003
```

1) How can I convert the above value (the output which is supposed to be the elapsed time to perform the loop as an example) to milliseconds? I am confused because the documentation says it returns the value in fractional seconds.

2) What is the meaning of `fractional seconds`? If it is the fraction on the right of a float of a second, say in `11.56` seconds, it is `0.56`, then how can I know the seconds value?

3) I am using it to compute elapsed time or performance time. I just need the time the function took.

I already used it so please try `not` to suggest another function. Clarify what I used to me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"in fractional seconds" means "in seconds represented as a floating-point number" (as opposed to C's [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time), for example, which returns an integral number of seconds).

So, to convert the value to milliseconds, multiply it by 1000.

Comment: That's what I thought. But can you check this post's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937708/what-is-a-fractional-second). It confused me. The answer says it is the fraction part of a number. Can you help me what am I missing?

Comment: @user9371654, well, English is confusing sometimes. You just ran into some kind of a terminology clash here.