# Measuring long time intervals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, intervals, timing

After searching about the different ways to measure time in Python 3.x, I've decided to use the *perf_counter()* function from the *time* module. When I tested it with a function that took some seconds to run it worked fine, but the code I wanna extract timing results from takes tens of hours to run.

Today I got the results and for my surprise the timing results were in the order of fractions of seconds, which is an absurd. Therefore, I come to ask you why does this happens and how to accurately measure long time intervals in Python 3.x.

The used code is as follows:

```
optimization_times = []
for i in range(30):
    # Search parameters on train set
    print("Round %d" % i)
    time_start = time.perf_counter()
    solution = metaheuristic.optimize()
    time_end = time.perf_counter()
    # Keep time spent
    optimization_times.append(time_end - time_start)
```

Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saw a wrap-around.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter):

> ... a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a **short** duration.

If your interval is tens of hours, you should stick with `time.time()`,
it has plenty of resolution for your needs.

If you think you really need an insane number of digits of precision,
then combine time.time() with perf_counter(),
and also have a program on the side
periodically record both values so you can
sync the perf_counter offset to global time.
Such a log corresponds
to making your 48-bit counter a few bits wider,
it lets you observe each wrap-around event.

Answer (score 0):

> #### [`time.perf_counter()` → float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)
>
> Return the value (**in fractional seconds**) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

--

> ### ["what is a fractional second?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937708/what-is-a-fractional-second)
>
> Fractional second is the part of the time that is not an integer. So if you have a time like 12345678.9 the fractional second is 0.9
>
> (Basile Starynkevitch)

---

Possible solution is [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html):

```py
import timeit
import time

def func():
    time.sleep(0.05)

timeit.timeit(lambda: func(), number=10)
```

Outputs:

```
0.528169795999986
```

Comment: I believe this definition of fractional second does not hold in this case, since time.perf_counter() can measure more than ten seconds with no problem